# Setting Up Odoo Website from Server to Local Host

Tags: windows, server, wamp, odoo

Well the big issue I got is how can I run Odoo on my local host (WAMP). I have gotten the files from my company server however I need to test and migrate it so I am trying to run it on my local host however I have had no luck even accessing a single web page. I have copied and pasted the folder into the correct location. However if I try to access it it just takes me to a 404 error or a directory listing page (folder structure)

**So just wondering if anyone knows how I can run odoo files from my server to my local host????**

Comment: do you mean you want to start odoo at your localside from local files? Are you using WAMP for that?

Comment: i have wamp installed. I downloaded the odoo files from the server placed it in the wamp folder however i cannot even load it

Comment: is it necesaary to use WAMP for this. on which operating system you are working on? Odoo can be run without WAMP also.

Comment: i took the files off a linux server and am trzing to run them on windows operating system

Comment: do you have python installed on your windows machine? Odoo can be started with python, as the base language is python for Odoo. We run it using python in linux.

Comment: i know for a fact we do the same. I just cant figure out how to do it

Comment: did you tried going to the Odoo directory and type : 'python openerp-server'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copying folder structure is not enough for proper migration. You should also have access to the **Odoo** database: it uses [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/), and you should either have access to your company database server or duplicate database. It's even more important than files in **Odoo** directory.

Moreover, for running **Odoo** on your local machine, you should not have **WAMP** installed - [python](https://www.python.org/) with some modules and [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/) is enough.

If you want "clean" install and then using some migration tools, you can [install](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/setup/install.html#setup-install-packaged) **Odoo** into your machine (I provided link for 9.0 version, for 8.0 you can use [this link](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/setup/install.html#setup-install-packaged) or choose corresponding version on the **Odoo** installation page) - this method will setup all necessary environment automatically, but you should manually upload your data to the fresh install.

Installation from sources is some more tricky, but still not very hard. You can find instructions in [official website](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/setup/install.html#setup-install-source).

After this you can check directory structure and copy your custom addons, templates, design or content from existing directory structure to the fresh one. Don't forget about database - without it you won't have huge part of your data available on company server.

For running **Odoo** you should run `odoo.py` with your python from your Odoo directory (you should have **python 2.7.x** installed on your machine).

By default **Odoo** uses port **8069**, i. e. for accessing it you should type in browser

`localhost:8069`

For more detailed instructions please refer to [Odoo documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/index.html).